# Type conversion error in Crystal report, A number is required here..

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'd like to filter data in crystal report viewer with type data integer for example: age, but my code does not work and CR throws an error message.

Below is my code

```
  Dim age As Integer
    age = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    Try
        Me.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{biodata.age}  = '" & age.ToString & "'"
        Me.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

This is the error message.

> A number is required here ... 
>   Details:....

Can someone please guide me how to fix this issue?

Comment: I have edited your question and got rid of Blah blah that you posted. Not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, posting ***Bla blah*** is not suggested. Its just a matter of copy paste, so might as well put complete error text.

**Your answer:**

Your database field `{biodata.age}` seems to be Numeric. In that case, CR does not like your "ToString" conversion. You have 2 options:

1) Remove `ToString` in code and pass "`age`" as a int.

```
Me.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{biodata.age}  = & age &)"
```

2) If you want to continue using `age.ToString` then use `ToNumber(age.ToString)`. This will convert your string to int within CR. 
Something like below, I am not sure about vb syntax, but you dont need single quotes.

```
Me.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{biodata.age}  = ToNumber(& age.ToString &)"
```

To check what type the field is just Right click on Database Fields in the Field Explorer and check show field type.